# Stata code to convert variables available at a daily interval into weekly

Tags: statistics, stata

I'm working with a panel dataset for 400 car models with daily observations that runs from 1 Jan 2019 to 30 June 2022. I need to convert them into weekly observations for each model using Stata codes, but can't find the appropriate command.

I used the code below, but it appears that Stata is counting Tuesday to Monday as a week. This will not give me correct weekly values as I need the calculations to run from Monday to Sunday.

```
format date %tdCCYY-NN-DD_Day
gen int week = wofd(date)
order week, after (date)
format week %twCCYY-WW
```

`````
car    date          week  milg fuelc
A1008   2019-01-01 Tue  2019-01 1   6
A1008   2019-01-02 Wed  2019-01 2   8
A1008   2019-01-03 Thu  2019-01 5   4
A1008   2019-01-04 Fri  2019-01 4   7
A1008   2019-01-05 Sat  2019-01 5   8
A1008   2019-01-06 Sun  2019-01 1   5
A1008   2019-01-07 Mon  2019-01 2   9
A1008   2019-01-08 Tue  2019-02 5   8
A1008   2019-01-09 Wed  2019-02 6   9
F2906   2019-01-01 Tue  2019-01 1   6
F2906   2019-01-02 Wed  2019-01 4   8
F2906   2019-01-03 Thu  2019-01 2   6
F2906   2019-01-04 Fri  2019-01 4   9
F2906   2019-01-05 Sat  2019-01 1   9
F2906   2019-01-06 Sun  2019-01 4   9
F2906   2019-01-07 Mon  2019-01 2   6
F2906   2019-01-08 Tue  2019-02 6   9
F2906   2019-01-09 Wed  2019-02 5   8
RR389   2019-01-01 Tue  2019-01 1   7
RR389   2019-01-02 Wed  2019-01 5   4
RR389   2019-01-03 Thu  2019-01 2   7
RR389   2019-01-04 Fri  2019-01 6   9
RR389   2019-01-05 Sat  2019-01 1   9
RR389   2019-01-06 Sun  2019-01 4   8
RR389   2019-01-07 Mon  2019-01 1   7````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You are using the inbuilt function `wofd()` and as documented this applies Stata's definition of weeks:

1. week 1 starts on 1 January, always
2. there are 52 weeks in each year, always
3. hence week 52 is either 8 or 9 days long.

Thus Stata weeks are not defined as starting on any particular day of the week.

I've never encountered any user wanting precisely this definition.

You want weeks starting on Mondays. Here is token code for a sandbox dataset. The small art flows from using the `dow()` function to get what you want.

```
clear
set obs 31 
gen date = mdy(12,31,2018) + _n
format date %td 

gen dow = dow(date)
gen str3 DOW = word("`c(Wdays)'", 1 + dow)
gen week = sum(dow == 1)
bysort week (date) : gen first = date[1] - cond(dow[1] == 0, 6, dow[1] - 1)  
format first %td 

list, sepby(week)

     +------------------------------------------+
     |      date   dow   DOW   week       first |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. | 01jan2019     2   Tue      0   31dec2018 |
  2. | 02jan2019     3   Wed      0   31dec2018 |
  3. | 03jan2019     4   Thu      0   31dec2018 |
  4. | 04jan2019     5   Fri      0   31dec2018 |
  5. | 05jan2019     6   Sat      0   31dec2018 |
  6. | 06jan2019     0   Sun      0   31dec2018 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  7. | 07jan2019     1   Mon      1   07jan2019 |
  8. | 08jan2019     2   Tue      1   07jan2019 |
  9. | 09jan2019     3   Wed      1   07jan2019 |
 10. | 10jan2019     4   Thu      1   07jan2019 |
 11. | 11jan2019     5   Fri      1   07jan2019 |
 12. | 12jan2019     6   Sat      1   07jan2019 |
 13. | 13jan2019     0   Sun      1   07jan2019 |
     |------------------------------------------|
 14. | 14jan2019     1   Mon      2   14jan2019 |
 15. | 15jan2019     2   Tue      2   14jan2019 |
 16. | 16jan2019     3   Wed      2   14jan2019 |
 17. | 17jan2019     4   Thu      2   14jan2019 |
 18. | 18jan2019     5   Fri      2   14jan2019 |
 19. | 19jan2019     6   Sat      2   14jan2019 |
 20. | 20jan2019     0   Sun      2   14jan2019 |
     |------------------------------------------|
 21. | 21jan2019     1   Mon      3   21jan2019 |
 22. | 22jan2019     2   Tue      3   21jan2019 |
 23. | 23jan2019     3   Wed      3   21jan2019 |
 24. | 24jan2019     4   Thu      3   21jan2019 |
 25. | 25jan2019     5   Fri      3   21jan2019 |
 26. | 26jan2019     6   Sat      3   21jan2019 |
 27. | 27jan2019     0   Sun      3   21jan2019 |
     |------------------------------------------|
 28. | 28jan2019     1   Mon      4   28jan2019 |
 29. | 29jan2019     2   Tue      4   28jan2019 |
 30. | 30jan2019     3   Wed      4   28jan2019 |
 31. | 31jan2019     4   Thu      4   28jan2019 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```

You may have something else in mind, but I recommend labelling each week by the start date; using the end date is equally easy.

`search week, sj` finds related discussions. The 2010 publication is likely to be as far as you need to go at present.

```
. search week, sj

Search of official help files, FAQs, Examples, and Stata Journals

SJ-22-2 dm0107_1  . . .  Erratum: Stata tip 145: Numbering weeks within months
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q2/22   SJ 22(2):465--466                                (no commands)
        errata for tip on numbering weeks within months

SJ-22-1 dm0107  . . . . . . . . . Stata tip 145: Numbering weeks within months
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q1/22   SJ 22(1):224--230                                (no commands)
        tip on numbering weeks within months

SJ-19-3 dm0100  . . . . . . . . . .  Speaking Stata: The last day of the month
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q3/19   SJ 19(3):719--728                                (no commands)
        discusses three related problems about getting the last day
        of the month in a new variable

SJ-12-4 dm0065_1  . . . . . Stata tip 111: More on working with weeks, erratum
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q4/12   SJ 12(4):765                                     (no commands)
        lists previously omitted key reference

SJ-12-3 dm0065  . . . . . . . . . .  Stata tip 111: More on working with weeks
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q3/12   SJ 12(3):565--569                                (no commands)
        discusses how to convert data presented in yearly and weekly
        form to daily dates and how to aggregate such data to months
        or longer intervals

SJ-10-4 dm0052  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Stata tip 68: Week assumptions
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  N. J. Cox
        Q4/10   SJ 10(4):682--685                                (no commands)
        tip on Stata's solution for weeks and on how to set up
        your own alternatives given different definitions of the
        week
```

EDIT An important corollary is this: If you don't use Stata's definition of weeks, but you use another, none of Stata's machinery or syntax for weeks is at all applicable. That includes weekly display formats. Here is a demonstration:

```
. di wofd(mdy(5, 12, 2023))
3294

. di %tw  wofd(mdy(5, 12, 2023))
2023w19
```

As I write the date is 12 May 2023, and Stata's definition of week (52 weeks per year, and week 0 being the first week in 1960) implies that that day is in week 3294. Stata understands its own definitions and a weekly date display format shows that 12 May 2023 is in week 19 of 2023. But that display is only produced with week value 3294. Even in principle, it can't match any definition of week that allows weeks to span two years, or for 53 weeks to start or end in any calendar year.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick, the code solved the issue. I also managed to calculate the total milg fuelc for each week using the code                                                 
````collapse (sum) milg fuelc, by (week first car)```` I'm trying to run an time series analysis with an interruption so I need a way to generate the time and change.I tried using ````format first %tw```` but the command generates time as 1,8,15 etc. instead of 1,2,3,.... Is there a way to correct this, or create a variable that lists the dates under 'first' incrementally?Thanks

Comment: No, no, no; just as `wofd()` is based on a definition of week that you don't want to use, so also the display format `%tw` has no application whatsoever to weeks defined using this code. But your question is already answered above; the variable `week` above should serve for time series analysis (subject to your having repeated values, possibly).

Comment: Please seed EDIT for a fuller story on display format.

Comment: Indeed. My sandbox is not a panel dataset, so you need to adapt the code to your different set-up -- or write more general code.   `gen week = floor((date - mdy(12, 31, 2018))/7)` does not depend on the dataset order or structure. (FYI, the data example in your question was not created using `dataex` and is not usable without some engineering, one reason for creating my own example.)

Comment: Thank you Nick, that clarifies the confusion. However, I noticed that the code above doesn't work correctly for my panel data. The new variable 'week' generated using the code 

''''gen week = sum(dow == 1)'''' 
 Confuses observations for the final week i.e. Mon 27/6/22 to Sun 30/6/22 for car1 and the first week i.e. Tue  1/1/2019 to Sun 6/1/2019 for car2. Both of these date correspond to week 182-which is not correct. Sorry if the question is basic, but is there a way to correct this?

Comment: This comment copies one earlier and has already been replied to.

Comment: It took me some time to get my head around the new date variable and limitations of the Stata syntax when applied to it but finally got there. Thank you so much for your help.